UDF to evaluate a text string which represents a complex formula
From investigation on the internet I have determined how to do this for a simple problem.  I am using the VBA function shown here.
Option Explicit
Function fxTextToFormulaUDF(text As String)
    Application.Volatile
    fxTextToFormulaUDF = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(text)
End Function


I wish to create a formula which uses, as a portion of it, text from a cell.  For a very simple problem this works fine. See this example:
   A         D            C          D       E  

1  Item       Order_num
2  abc124        200
3            'XLOOKUP(A2,ID,
4
5      ID       Description   Quantity   Cost  Order_num
6     abc123   A             1          10       100
7     abc124   B             2          20       200
8     abc125   C             3          30       300
The formula in cell D2 is =fxTextToFormulaUDF(right(D3,len(D3)-1),D1).
With this one can change the value in cell D1 and the appropriate value is displayed in cell D2.
However, for a more complex XLOOKUP formula it doesn't work.  See the image included.  Here the XLOOKUP is retrieving values from a file on disk.  I'm getting a #REF! error.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!
See above.  Perhaps retrieving from the disk is the issue.
